# Conditional Formatting based on check box in a separate google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have 2 separate google sheets (different urls) and I want to be able to check a box on one sheet and have that highlight a row of data on another google sheet. Is this even possible

Criteria
Google sheet (url 1) contains all data with one column being a check box that corresponds to a row of data on google sheet (url 1)
When box is checked (TRUE) on google sheet (url 1) I need conditional formatting to execute on google sheet (url 2)

Is this something that can be coded in App Scripts?

I have tried all formulas that relate to conditional formatting from one sheet to another within the same workbook but I need the same outcome but for it to be from one sheet in one workbook to another sheet in andother workbook

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Apps Script, specifically an onEdit trigger for this. I'll give you the idea and you can create what you need from this.

Suppose checkboxes are on Spreadsheet1 SheetA and you want to manipulate Spreadsheet2 SheetB.
Create an AppsScript project on Spreadsheet1 and create the onEdit function and trigger in this project.

In your onEdit function, check the edited cell value and range, see if it matches the column you have checkboxes. If so, get the row number of the edited cell into a variable, then use that variable in a getRange function on SheetB to achieve whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  Let me give you an example here.

I have a checkbox in Sheet1!A1 below:

[image]

I have "Yes" and "No" in Sheet2!A1:A6 below:

[image]

The cells containing "Yes" are highlighted by means of this conditional formatting setup in Sheet2:

[image]

The formula I have used is:

=AND(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$1"),A1="Yes")

The key to referring to another sheet with conditional formatting is using the INDIRECT function.  I use it sparingly as it can slow down sheet performance if there is a lot of data to analyze.